# Xamarin iOS: System.ExecutionEngineException. Details: attempting to JIT compile method while running in aot-only mode

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios

In my project I use `Microsoft.Data.Sqlite` package to work with sqlite databases. On Android platform all things work ok, but on iOS platform I get this exception when application tries to interact with sqlite database:

> Xamarin iOS: System.ExecutionEngineException. Details: attempting to
> JIT compile method '(wrapper delegate invoke) void
> :invoke_calvirt_void_SqliteParameter_Sqlite_Type)' while
> running in aot-only mode.

The strange thing is that all things work ok on simulator, but on actual device I get the exception.

How can I fix that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To fix this issue, open iOS Xamarin project, iOS build properties and enable option `Enable the Mono interpreter`. After that rebuild the application and redeploy on the actual device.

[image: screenshot]