# Json Serialization Exception : Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException

Tags: c#, ios, json, iphone, serialization

```
interface IMyClass
{
    DateTime Date { get; set; }
}
class MyClass : IMyClass
{
    public DateTime Date { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;
}

class MyClass1
{
   public IMyClass PP;
}

public void SerializeJson()
{
    MyClass1 myClass = new MyClass1();
    myClass.PP = new MyClass();
    myClass.PP.Date = DateTime.Now;
    string result = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myClass, Formatting.None, new
            JsonSerializerSettings
            {
                // We must add TypeNameHandling because this class implements numerous 
                // interfaces and the JSON
                // converter needs to know which concrete classes to deserailize those 
                // into
                TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Auto
            });
}
```

I have tried to explain issue with class structure example above.
I am working on MAUI application, using rider IDE, When I am trying to Serialize the Json using NewtonSoft.Json Nuget it throws exception.

```
2023-05-11 18:23:25.620 project[2021:735465] Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: Error getting value from 'Date' on 'MyNamespace.Test.MyFile+MyClass'.
2023-05-11 18:23:25.620 project[2021:735465]  ---> System.ExecutionEngineException: Attempting to JIT compile method '(wrapper delegate-invoke) System.DateTime <Module>:invoke_callvirt_DateTime_MyFile/MyClass (MyNamespace.Test.MyFile/MyClass)' while running in aot-only mode. See https://docs.microsoft.com/xamarin/ios/internals/limitations for more information.
2023-05-11 18:23:25.620 project[2021:735465]    at System.Linq.Expressions.Interpreter.FuncCallInstruction`2[[MyNamespace.Test.MyFile.MyClass, MyNamespace, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null],[System.DateTime, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]].Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.Interpreter.Interpreter.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
2023-05-11 18:23:25.620 project[2021:735465]    at System.Linq.Expressions.Interpreter.LightLambda.Run(Object[] arguments)
   at System.Dynamic.Utils.DelegateHelpers.FuncThunk1[Object,Object](Func`2 handler, Object t1)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.ExpressionValueProvider.GetValue(Object target)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
2023-05-11 18:23:25.620 project[2021:735465]    at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.ExpressionValueProvider.GetValue(Object target)
2023-05-11 18:23:25.620 project[2021:735465]    at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.CalculatePropertyValues(JsonWriter writer, Object value, JsonContainerContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonProperty property, JsonContract& memberContract, Object& memberValue)
2023-05-11 18:23:25.620 project[2021:735465]    at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeObject(JsonWriter writer, Object value, JsonObjectContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract collectionContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)
2023-05-11 18:23:25.620 project[2021:735465]    at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeValue(JsonWriter writer, Object value, JsonContract valueContract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)
2023-05-11 18:23:25.620 project[2021:735465]    at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeObject(JsonWriter writer, Object value, JsonObjectContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract collectionContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeValue(JsonWriter writer, Object value, JsonContract valueContract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)
2023-05-11 18:23:25.620 project[2021:735465]    at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.Serialize(JsonWriter jsonWriter, Object value, Type objectType)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.SerializeInternal(JsonWriter jsonWriter, Object value, Type objectType)
2023-05-11 18:23:25.620 project[2021:735465]    at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize(JsonWriter jsonWriter, Object value, Type objectType)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObjectInternal(Object value, Type type, JsonSerializer jsonSerializer)
2023-05-11 18:23:25.620 project[2021:735465]    at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Object value, Type type, Formatting formatting, JsonSerializerSettings settings)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Object value, Formatting formatting, JsonSerializerSettings settings)
2023-05-11 18:23:25.620 project[2021:735465]    at MyNamespace.Test.MyFile.SerializeJson()
```

When I try to debug this on real iPhone device it throws exception but works on iPhone simulator and also works on real Android device.
I am not sure what is the issue causing with iPhone device.

Can someone suggests any solution to this ?

Comment: try https://stackoverflow.com/a/69994944/11392290

Answer (score 1):

Enable mono Interpreter worked for me.

```
<MtouchInterpreter>all</MtouchInterpreter>
```

Comment: More information on how to correctly enable it can be found here. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/macios/interpreter?view=net-maui-8.0